# Why is getElementById() returning NULL?

Tags: javascript, html

When I click on the text in my `"opener"` window, I open a new window. In this new window, instead of the text `"Bye, World"`, I would like to show `"Hello World"`, though my code is not working for some reason.
***TypeError: wnd.document.getElementById(...) is null***

What is wrong?
Thanks!

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">


        function funct()
        {
            var wnd = window.open("index.html","","width=500, height=500");         
            wnd.document.getElementById('hello').style.display = "inline";
            wnd.document.getElementById('goodbye').style.display = "none";
        }

    </script>

    <style type="text/css">
            #hello{
                display: none;
            }

            #goodbye{
                display: inline;
            }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <p id="hello">Hello World</p>
    <p id="goodbye" onclick="funct()">Bye, World</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it was just modified by @patsy issa (with an amazing response time!!)

Comment: The contents of the page do not load immediately, and the `.open()` call doesn't wait.

Comment: but why is it working, with document.write("Hello World")?

Comment: @user3357969 If you could refrain from using profanity on SO that would be great.

Comment: I forgot to remove it from one place, dont worry jaysus

Comment: @user3357969 You re-edited in after I removed it...

Comment: yes because it is not #goodbye, but it is #bye

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want, you can do like this.

```
function funct()
{
    var wnd = window.open("index.html","","width=500, height=500");         
    wnd.window.onload = function(){
        wnd.document.getElementById('hello').style.display = "inline";
        wnd.document.getElementById('goodbye').style.display = "none";
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your #hello is referring to the main window and not to the window that is being opened, maybe you should consider making a new text node dynamically when the new window is loaded because the #hello life resides in the main window.

Answer (score -1):

why you need `wnd` use only ?

```
document.getElementById('hello').style.display = "inline";
```

Comment: I want to edit my newly opened window, not the opener

Comment: those who are down-voting please share some phrase so that we could know why you do this. We are all here to help each other not to play up-vote down-vote game

Comment: @Ron your answer basically does not work to solve the original problem. The OP is interested in affecting the page loaded by a `window.open()` call, not the current page.